# Finding the physical size of the touch digitizer in Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, touch, gesture

### Question

How does one go about determing the physical size of the touch (or pen) digitizer in Windows 8.1 using the WinAPI?

### Scenario

I'm using the [GetPointerFrameTouchInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454883(v=vs.85).aspx) API which returns a [POINTER_TOUCH_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454907(v=vs.85).aspx) struct with an embedded [POINTER_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454907(v=vs.85).aspx) struct.

The POINTER_INFO struct has a ptHimetricLocation member which indicates the physical location of a touch with 10 uM resolution (which is way more consistent to work with for gesture recognition).

But, after doing some calculations using the ptHiMetricLocation, it's not possible to accurately find the corresponding pixel location without knowing the physical size of the digitizer.

### Qualifier

To clarify, this is *not* a question about the physical screen size. It's about the touch digitizer (or the pen digitizer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it turns out this is actually really easy, as long as you have a handle to the device. Just use the [GetPointerDeviceRects()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802886(v=vs.85).aspx) function =]